# Android: Force closing for lack of permission which is located in the manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm trying to delete a bookmark using contentResolver.delete() and I get force close for missing permission "**com.android.broswer.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS**" but it's in the manifest...

**this is in the manifest (outside `<application></application>`)**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.broswer.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS"></uses-permission>
```

**this is the method:**

```
public void deleteBookmark(Cursor cur, long id) {
        getContentResolver().delete(BOOKMARKS_URI, "_id = " + id, null);
    }
```

(ignore the unused Cursor)

**and this is the logcat:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime(26750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26750): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
 com.android.browser.BrowserProvider uri content://browser/bookmarks from pid=26
750, uid=10001 requires com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1
260)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionF
romParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:160)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionF
romParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.delete(C
ontentProviderNative.java:472)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(Conten
tResolver.java:675)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.deleteBookmark(.java:167)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.onContextItemSe
lected(.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activ
ity.java:2199)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$
ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2744)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.i
nvoke(MenuItemImpl.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.pe
rformItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelp
er.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$Aler
tParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:875)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(A
dapterView.java:284)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(List
View.java:3382)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(A
bsListView.java:1696)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.jav
a:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
21)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(26750):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea why it says Permission Denial when it's clearly in the manifest? Maybe my code is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6f994ddc2f010708) post

It says the following

**Anything in the com.android.* package is a private API and you should not
rely on it as it could break in a future update.**

**Things that are public are (usually) android.* (minus the leading com.)
and are described in the SDK documentation.**

Comment: Yeah but this is true for OS versions other than Froyo and I'm working on Froyo 2.2 SDK 8... the READ permission works... so it's weird the WRITE one isn't. :\

Comment: Also, my add bookmark function works great... and I guess it uses the WRITE permission.

Comment: It might be that Android might have blocked write permissions to bookmark for 3rd party apps since any application should not be able to delete your bookmarks stored on a browser..some security constraint. However reading or even adding a new bookmark will not do much harm there...

Comment: But there are applications in the Market which allows editing and deleting browser bookmarks... any chance my code causes this?

Comment: Yes you are correct this issue has been fixed in 2.2 as per bug tracker. I assume that you are also compiling your code in 2.2 http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7232

Comment: Yes I'm compiling in android 2.2 sdk 8... that's why i'm surprised it's not working :\

Comment: So no one have a solution? :-(

Answer (score 1):

OMG! sorry for this, my mistake!

it should be BROWSER :0)

a typo wasted my whole weekend...

BTW: 
is supported only in Android 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that you're typed `uses-permission` and not `uses-permissions` (Singular).

A subtle change like this can ruin your weekend.